# second monitor won't display

Tags: graphics-card, display

my problem is this:

I have one video card (radeon HD 4350) and 2 monitors (dell). the first monitor works using dvi-to-dvi. the second does not, using hdmi-to-dvi. the monitor does not register any input. however when I use vga-to-vga, the second monitor does work, with a typically low vga resolution. we have tested the hdmi-to-dvi cable, so why does the monitor not register any input?

using Windows Vista.

I have installed all the latest drivers, done all the basic stuff etc.

Comment: This should be posted on superuser.com not serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the display in Display Properties and set its resolution, color depth, and refresh rate accordingly?

If so, open the Catalyst Control Center and switch to Advanced View. Confirm that the settings for your display(s) are correct in the Monitor Properties branch and try disabling EDID if it is not. Check in the Display Options branch that `Detect whenever Catalyst™ Control Center is opened.` is checked. If your monitor is still not being detected, try using the `Force` options.